# Shell script to read input from a text file

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I am working on a shell script that reads input from a text file

```
Path1:/home/demo/path0
FILE1:test.dat,sample.txt
PATH2:/home/demo/path1
FILE2:demo1.dat,xyzb.txt
PATH3:/home/demo/path2
FILE3: samplecsv.csv,somepdf.pdf
```

I need output of `FILE1` files `test.dat`, `sample.txt` in a separate folder, `FILE2:demo1.dat,xyzb.txt` file paths in separate folder.

I have tried below but not getting desired result

```
val=`cat filename`
Count=${#val[@]}
for (( i=0; i<$Count ; i++))
do
var=`echo ${val[i]} | sed -e 's/\.//g'`
one=$(grep PATH1 ${val[i]} | awk -F':' '{print $2}');
two=$(grep FILE1 ${val[i]} | awk -F':' '{print $2}');
done
echo $var
echo $one
echo $two
```

Comment: `${#val[@]}` is used to get an array size.  ``val=`cat filename` `` doesn't create an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notes:

1. [Don't use `for` to read the lines of a file](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)
2. Use `$(...)` instead of `` `...` `` -- see
   https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2006
   for more details.
3. `awk` can do what `grep` does, so you don't need both in a pipeline. However, in this scenario, you don't need either.

I would write

```bsh
# so the case statement below will match case-insensitively
shopt -s nocasematch

paths=()
files=()

while IFS=: read -r key value; do
    case $key in
        PATH*) paths+=("$value") ;;
        FILE*) files+=("$value") ;;
    esac
done < filename

declare -p paths files
```

This outputs

```
declare -a paths=([0]="/home/demo/path0" [1]="/home/demo/path1" [2]="/home/demo/path2")
declare -a files=([0]="test.dat,sample.txt" [1]="demo1.dat,xyzb.txt" [2]=" samplecsv.csv,somepdf.pdf")
```

and you can iterate over the arrays as desired.

Comment: Thankyou for the inputs just another thing is that if I use positional parameters like path=$1 and file=$2 inside a function should I iterate the same way?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What are "path" and "file" in the context of your example code?